# What is the recommended design for setting configurations upon the receipt of an intent in an android application with multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-activity

I have an Android Application with multiple activities where each activity corresponds to a different screen/view and they are actually somehow sequential (in the sense that one internal activity launches the other after a certain event).

In that context, I want to be able to receive an external Intent that sets some configurations from my Application (configurations potentially in common for all Activities) but I do not want that to change the current view.

How should I do that? Is there a way to bind a broadcast receiver to the application iteself rather than a specific activity?

Aren't broadcast receivers attached directly to the activities? Looking at the [Android tutorial on intents] (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#npex) all the intent filters are attached to different activities in the Manifest file. However looking at this [tutorial] (http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html), I see that it is possible to declare Receiver on the manifest directly under the application.

If I attach it directly to a class under the Application (on the manifest), does that mean that the code will be executed and the frontground activity (view) will not change?

Comment: what kind of configuration you want to set ? Please give an example

Comment: the configuration is internal to my application. You can think of a variable on the Application and which therefore works as a global variable regarding the activities, and it will be used by some of them.

Comment: Broadcast receiver are not directly attached with the activity. Even there can be an application with receiver only. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504906/how-to-create-broadcastreceiver-without-activity

Answer (score 0):

Here There may be different design pattern could be used based on your requirement.

If you want to have some persistent information in memory then you can use shared preferences for whole application.

You can have one broadcast receiver which would be intended to get some external intent containing all configuration values.

Each time , you can check the external configuration hash with internal hash ( which is stored in shared preferences ) , If you find some difference , then you can update the shared preferences .

So , better approach would be that you can have a configuration class and this class object can be saved in shared preferences.

There are several ways to save object in shared preferences.

so , Now in each activity , you can read the preferences in onResume()  to apply new configuration .

If you don't want to persist the conf object in shared preferences , then you can have static object of Conf class and that can be initialized in application class.

eg-

```
  public class BaseClass extends Application {
  public static Conf conf ;
  ....
  }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

So application class is a Base class for those who need to maintain global application state
rather than component (Activity , Service ) specific.

Comment: The shared preference or Application global variable is not the problem. The main question is, where do I attach the broadcast receiver? I need to get the configuration coming from an intent, but I would like to stay on the current Activity (view) regardless of what it is-

Comment: Its ok...Broadcast receiver are always attached with application. They can be registered with application context . You can just have a separate receiver file . Broadcast receiver run in different thread . It does not run in Activity Thread.