# Start application without activity, my Broadcast Receiver not work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my app, I have a Broadcast Receiver for catching the message sent to my phone

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.qmobile.ows.SMS_Receiver"
            android:enabled="true" 
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />                  
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

If I start app with activity GUI, the BroadCast Receiver works normally.

I want to start my application without activity and do not show icon app, so I **remove** this code below from my activity

```
 <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

And after that, Broadcast Receiver do not work.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Please put your onRecive() code.

Comment: Simple Background application stop working after Android 3.0 version.  [CommonsBlog](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Android OS does not allow  `BroadcastReceiver` to receive **some important** broadcast(`android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` must be one of it) if the app´s process is not alive.It was designed to against the evil apps. If you have an activity running,your process is alive and so your receiver is allowed to receive the broadcast.

I think you can make a **transparent** `activity` and use startService to start a `service` in background,then finish the `activity`.As your service is running ,your process is alive,so the Android OS will let you to receive the broadcast.

Comment: This is not true! A Broadcast can receive this even if the app is not "alive". The reason for this problem is that as of android 3.1 and higher all broadcasts require the user to run your app at least once in order to work. This is designed to prevent malware.

Comment: In the android 3.1 api preview "Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but are not yet launched and when they are manually stopped by the user" and Stopped applications can't receive broadcasts

Answer (score 4):

***For Android 3.1 and higher***,

You have to launch one of your activities before any manifest-registered BroadcastReceiver will work.

See developer docs specifically the section -

[Launch controls on stopped applications](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html) for android-3.1

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing Broadcast receiver without an Activity then you should edit your run configuration.
When the Edit configuration dialog appears, select the Do not launch Activity option so that the activity is installed but not launched and click on the Run button
This will launch the application without activity.

This could help you:

**Creating and Sending the Broadcast Intent**

Having created the framework for the SendBroadcast application, it is now time to implement the code to send the broadcast intent. This involves implementing the broadcastIntent() method specified previously as the onClick target of the Button view in the user interface. Locate and double click on the SendBroadcastActivity.java file and modify it to add the code to create and send the broadcast intent. Once modified, the source code for this class should read as follows:

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.sendbroadcast;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class SendBroadcastActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_broadcast);
    }

    public void broadcastIntent(View view)
    {
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setAction("com.ebookfrenzy.sendbroadcast");
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
       sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
.
.
.
}
```

**Creating the Broadcast Receiver**

In order to create the broadcast receiver, a new class needs to be created which subclasses the BroadcastReceiver superclass. Create a new project with the application name set to BroadcastReceiver and the company domain name set to com.ebookfrenzy, this time selecting the Add No Activity option before clicking on Finish.

Within the Project tool window, navigate to app -> java and right click on the package name. From the resulting menu, select the New -> Other -> Broadcast Receiver menu option, name the class MyReceiver and make sure the Exported and Enabled options are selected.

Once created, Android Studio will automatically load the new MyReceiver.java class file into the editor where it should read as follows:

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.broadcastreceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public MyReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

As can be seen in the code, Android Studio has generated a template for the new class and generated a stub for the onReceive() method. A number of changes now need to be made to the class to implement the required behavior. Remaining in the MyReceiver.java file, therefore, modify the code so that it reads as follows:

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.broadcastreceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public MyReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast Intent Detected.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }   

}
```

The code for the broadcast receiver is now complete.

**Configuring a Broadcast Receiver in the Manifest File**
In common with other Android projects, BroadcastReceiver has associated with it a manifest file named AndroidManifest.xml.

This file needs to publicize the presence of the broadcast receiver and must include an intent filter to specify the broadcast intents in which the receiver is interested. When the BroadcastReceiver class was created in the previous section, Android Studio automatically added a `<receiver>` element to the manifest file. All that remains, therefore, is to add an `<intent-filter>` element within the `<receiver>` declaration appropriately configured for the custom action string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ebookfrenzy.broadcastreceiver.broadcastreceiver" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
         <intent-filter>
                <action 
          android:name="com.ebookfrenzy.sendbroadcast" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

With the manifest file completed, the broadcast example is ready to be tested.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Here's what worked for me. I created a launcher activity. Removed the call to setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add DEFAULT category in your intent filter

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```